# Script php no java ? corre no background?

Tags: php, java, android

Eu tenho uma dúvida. Eu tenho um *script* que demora cerca de 40 segundos a executar. Estou a pensar então se mandar correr no android, o utilizador se não estiver disposto a esperar os 40 segundos, o que acontece ele encerra a meio a aplicação mas o *script* fica a correr ou para?

Comment: O script php do webservice no servidor? Minha aposta é que ele não para. Pode até ser que pare mas você não deve contar com isso. O fato de não parar resulta num problema de falta de consistência entre o cliente e os servidor cujo caminho para resolver passa por tornar a requisição do script *segura* e/ou *idempotente*: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/restful-web-services/9780596809140/ch01s04.html

Answer (score 0):

Você *pode* configurar o script PHP para interromper caso a conexão feche, pela função ignore_user_abort(). Mas o script também tem de mandar dados periodicamente (a cada poucos segundos) e chamar flush() porque só mandando dados é que o fechamento vai ser detectado. Vide o link http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php que tem inclusive exemplos.

Mas, na minha opinião, é uma péssima prática, mudar o comportamento do servidor em função do cliente manter a conexão aberta ou não. Exatamente o que você está tentando evitar -- um processamento longo ou pesado, ou um efeito colateral do tipo gravação no banco de dados?

Algumas operações pesadas como uma consulta SQL que demore 40s (que não deveria demorar isso em hipótese nenhuma) vão ser executadas atomicamente, ou seja, você não vai conseguir interrompê-la no meio, mesmo usado a técnica sugerida no primeiro parágrafo.

Seria legal conhecer mais detalhes desse processamento; procure complementar a pergunta para podermos complementar a resposta.